# Why commit does not cause deadlock

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have read mysql reference manual about the  InnoDB locks. I got that :
(from:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

---

INSERT sets an exclusive lock on the inserted row. This lock is an index-record lock, not a next-key lock (that is, there is no gap lock) and does not prevent other sessions from inserting into the gap before the inserted row.

Prior to inserting the row, a type of gap lock called an insert intention gap lock is set. This lock signals the intent to insert in such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the same index gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting at the same position within the gap. Suppose that there are index records with values of 4 and 7. Separate transactions that attempt to insert values of 5 and 6 each lock the gap between 4 and 7 with insert intention locks prior to obtaining the exclusive lock on the inserted row, but do not block each other because the rows are nonconflicting.

If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another session already has an exclusive lock. This can occur if another session deletes the row. Suppose that an InnoDB table t1 has the following structure:

CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, PRIMARY KEY (i)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
Now suppose that three sessions perform the following operations in order:

Session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

Session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

Session 3:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

Session 1:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

The first operation by session 1 acquires an exclusive lock for the row. The operations by sessions 2 and 3 both result in a duplicate-key error and they both request a shared lock for the row. When session 1 rolls back, it releases its exclusive lock on the row and the queued shared lock requests for sessions 2 and 3 are granted. At this point, sessions 2 and 3 deadlock: Neither can acquire an exclusive lock for the row because of the shared lock held by the other.

---

I made a experiment and I found is is the fact.

My question is :

(1)I found that, if I commit session 1, and deadlock did not happen. Why? When I commit session 1, The X row lock will also be released. So I do not understand.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an edge case that is not worth making more efficient.  Note that you had to get 3 sessions trying to grab the same row -- a rare happening.  And you did a ROLLBACK -- also rare.  So the deadlock that occurred is overkill, but not worth fixing.  For this reason, one must be prepared to handle deadlocks everywhere.

FYI, If this were 3 nodes of a Galera cluster, there would be errors on `COMMIT` that the code would have to handle.  I suspect there are even more combinations of strange things going on if you apply this transaction (with rollback or commit) multiple times to multiple nodes.

Now to your question...  Presumably the deadlock did not happen because one of the threads got the exclusive lock and the other was hit with a "wait" instead of a "deadlock".

Comment: Presumably the deadlock did not happen because one of the threads got the exclusive lock and the other was hit with a "wait" instead of a "deadlock".--- you mean that one of session2 and session 3 got the exclusive lock? Did not they request a shared lock after get a duplicate-key error?