# MySQL 5.7 - Deadlock on rollback, but not on commit, when using ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-deadlocks

*Background: I have an application that has many concurrent threads. In one spot, I want to update a certain database row, but I cannot be sure that the row actually exists yet. Hence, I need to either create the row OR update the row if it exists. But doing so, I ran into the problem I present here.*

Using MySQL 5.7, I came across a chain of events that causes a deadlock, but I cannot really understand why. Using three different client (`c1`, `c2` and `c3`), we perform the following chain of queries:

```
c1 > BEGIN;
c1 > INSERT INTO `user_points` (userid, points) VALUES (1,1) 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1;

c2 > INSERT INTO `user_points` (userid, points) VALUES (1,1) 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1;

c3 > INSERT INTO `user_points` (userid, points) VALUES (1,1) 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1;

c1 > ROLLBACK;
```

This series of queries will result in `c3` receiving a deadlock error, while `c2` performing its query without errors. **However**, if the last query by `c1` is a commit (instead of a rollback), then this series works just as expected.

Here is the table I use:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
    `userid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `points` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here is the deadlock reported by the InnoDB engine:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
180802  8:48:02
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1D69A6, ACTIVE 3 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 135, OS thread handle 0x7f3c9829b700, query id 12166 172.30.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO points (userid, points) VALUES (1,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 55819 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `temp`.`points` trx id 1D69A6 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1D69A7, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 137, OS thread handle 0x7f3c98239700, query id 12167 172.30.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO points (userid, points) VALUES (1,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = points + 1

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 55819 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `temp`.`points` trx id 1D69A7 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 55819 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `temp`.`points` trx id 1D69A7 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I've googled around a bit, and found a similar question to mine: [Why commit does not cause deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156969/why-commit-does-not-cause-deadlock). But wouldn't use of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` circumvent the issue described in that question? From the [MySQL reference page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html), I read the following:

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE differs from a simple INSERT in
>   that an exclusive lock rather than a shared lock is placed on the row
>   to be updated when a duplicate-key error occurs. An exclusive
>   index-record lock is taken for a duplicate primary key value. An
>   exclusive next-key lock is taken for a duplicate unique key value.

What I am trying to do feels like a pretty basic operation: create the row if it doesn't exist and update it if it already does. How can it be that it doesn't work?  What is actually going on here? And why do I receive a deadlock on rollback and not on commit?

Comment: The additional locks only come into play **when a duplicate-key error occurs**. The error doesn't actually happen, because the deadlock happens on the `insert`-part - exactly the same situation as in the question you linked. Not sure if you accept that the deadlock happens for the insert-only-case, but if you do, that might be the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I thought there were some kind of difference between the two procedures, because if you perform the query series from the linked question, the lock held by Transaction 2 is an S lock, while the lock held by Transaction 2 in this question is an X lock.

Comment: But it might still be as you say, that the error issue is already at the insert, and the lock types are a minor detail. If that is what's going on, it matters little whether I accept it or not, eh? :)

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB goals

1. Integrity of data.
2. Fast.
3. Minimize spurious deadlocks, etc, for edge cases.

Would you give up #1?  I doubt it.
Would you relax #2?  Maybe.  But that was not the decision for *this* edge case.

Feel free to file a bug at bugs.mysql.com ; maybe there is a fix that does not jeopardize #1 nor slow things down 'too' much.